# Pydantic - Converter "str" para "bool"

Tags: python

Boa tarde, gostaria de converter dados diretamente pelo pydantic.
Recebo em "str" dados "nao", "Sim", "na", Não" ... que precisa ser convertido para "bool".

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class Usuario(BaseModel):
    id: int
    nome: str
    ativo: bool
# Nota-se que tenho o ativo como sim, gostaria de saber sem tem como eu tratar isso direto no Pydantic.
# Na realidade recebo de diversas formas, mas gostaria de tratar diretamente no pydantic, mas não sei se tem como.
usuario_dados = {"id":1, "nome":"Eliton", "ativo":"Sim"} 

try:
    eliton = Usuario(**usuario_dados)
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e.json())
```

Comment: uma maneira bem porca de fazer isso, mas que se não for algo profissional poderia resolver, seria você colocar um `if` e verificar a primeira posição do `str` se for *n* atribua como `false`, se for `s` atribua como `true`

Answer (score 0):

Use o decorator `validator`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, validator


class Usuario(BaseModel):
    id: int
    nome: str
    ativo: str

    @validator('ativo')
    def converte_valores(cls, v):
        if v in ['Sim', 'sim']:
            return True
        if  v in ['Não', 'nao', 'na']:
            return False
        raise ValueError('valor nao valido')


usuario_dados = {"id":1, "nome":"Eliton", "ativo":"Sim"} 

try:
    eliton = Usuario(**usuario_dados)
    print(eliton)
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e.json())
```

Comment: Não teria que mudar o tipo de dados do atributo `ativo` para `bool`? Nunca usei o Pydantic, mas me parece estranho marcar o atributo como `str` e o validador retornar um booleano

Comment: Creio que seja irrelevante para o objetivo da biblioteca que é validar dados. Já que a entrada é uma string, então obviamente o tipo anotado será string, mas se vc acha que não está claro pode renomear a função decorada `converte_valores` com algum nome ainda mais explicito ou adicionar docstrings.  aqui a documentação que me baseei: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/

Comment: Sim, eu verifiquei a documentação também. Meu ponto é que o código está dizendo que `ativo` é do tipo `str` mas seu validador retorna `bool`, ou seja, seu validador retorna um dado inválido. Minha dúvida é se a biblioteca aceita isso, se não teria que mudar o valor no Model. Não acredito que isso seja irrelevante pois na documentação que você linkou diz: _validators should either return the parsed value_.. Ou seja, o retorno do validador vai ser o valor atribuído ao atributo `ativo`.

Comment: De qualquer maneira, se o autor da pergunta quiser, poderia usar como base a funçao [`bool_validator()`](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/bf9cc4a5e7903ada2e819a63fe2da011f292a143/pydantic/validators.py#L88) que a biblioteca usa para tipos `bool` e implemetar uma versão própria.

Comment: Confundi vc com o autor da pergunta. E quanto a sua observação, vc tbm pode responder a pergunta sugerindo sua solução.